# How can I compare the declared string “str” to string in the text file in the machine

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, autoit

I'm using selenium java with SSH -Client by AutoitX, I want to compare str from my code to the string in the text file in the machine.

Code:

```
    String str="abk123";
    x.send("cat txt.txt");  //in this text we have 1 string
    Thread.sleep(200);
    robot.keyPress(java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
    if (str==???) //(how can i use the string from the txt.txt file to compare?)
```

how can i use the string from the txt.txt file to compare?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You need to read the file in order to access to string..For reading a single line `Scanner` will do the job.

Answer (score 2):

1. Using File reading concept in java, read the contents of the file. And store the value to a variable (say variable name as 'actualStr')
2. Now you will have two variables with values. 'str' and 'actualStr'.
3. Compare using the string function